# MediaElement.SetSource() automatically plays my MP3

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaelement

I'm currently working on a Project in C# using the UWP.
I need to play a MP3 file but not immediately, but if I click a button in my app.
So I created a button "load MP3" which runs the following method:
[load MP3 method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnGzr.png)

```
private async void open_MP3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        mp3.AudioCategory = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AudioCategory.Media;


        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.List;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

        StorageFile sf = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        var stream = await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        mp3.SetSource(stream, sf.ContentType);
        //await Task.Delay(3500);
        //mp3.Pause();
    }
```

If I run this code the song I pick will be played instantly, without me clicking the play button I created.
If I set a break point at the `mp3.SetSource()` line the code won't play the song instantly. I tried to work around the problem with the `mp3.Pause()` method but had to insert a delay of 350 ms in order to work at all. If I choose the delay to long (like 3500ms here) the song starts playing and stops after 3,5 sec, obviously.

Since I have to time the start of the song exactly to milliseconds in order for my project to work the delay method is not ideal for me. Does anyone has an idea what is the problem with the `SetSource()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MediaElement` control has a `AutoPlay` property which is set to `true` by default (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.autoplay)). This means that whenever you set the source it will automatically start playing immediately after the source is loaded. To avoid this, just set the `AutoPlay` proprety to false:

```
mp3.AutoPlay = false;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped :-) . If it resolved your problem, please consider marking the answer as solution so that the question is resolved. Happy coding!